# Must a leaky tire plug be redone completely?

Tags: tires

I found a screw in my tire and plugged it last week. It has gone down about 1 PSI per day since then. I used soapy water and found a very slight leak (one bubble shows up and then slowly grows.)

Do I need to rip out the old plug and redo it? Or do I have other options like using more of the plug cement gel? Or carefully heating up the plug with a soldering torch to "cauterize" it?

I don't wanna deal with redoing it if I don't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tire plug is a TEMPORARY repair. Plugs are never designed to be permanent (although lots of people install a plug and never bother to have it repaired correctly--it's still not the right way to repair a puncture.). Yes, you have to remove it and repair it properly with a patch plug from the inside of the tire.

Comment: Just looking, even [Slime's instructions](https://storage.googleapis.com/slime-com/uploads/20290_Instructions.pdf) state it is only for temporary use until you can get it to a service center for repair. However, I've only EVER used them until the tire wears out and not a second later. The rope tire plugs work that well. I've used 100's of them and never had an issue with them.

Comment: I've implied this before and I'll say it again,  tire plugs can be _exceptionally reliable_

Comment: Id just like to add that in some countries plug repairs may not be legal.